# Convert seconds to Timestamp, and compare values, Firebase, React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need to compare two values, as you see in my code below.

Point is that they are in different formats, and i need them to compare.

Here is my code(daysToLeave is allways number 1-3 - this value match 1-3 days):

```
const tomorrow = new Date();
const tmp = tomorrow.getDate() + daysToLeave;
tomorrow.setDate(tmp);

console.log("eventDate.date", eventDate?.date);
console.log("tommorrow", tomorrow);

if (eventDate?.date < tomorrow) {
  console.log("success");
}
```

Here are my console.logs:
[image]

Comment: I dont mind which of values will be changed, all i just need to if statment work, on dependence of daysToLeave. It means when its 2 days before today, it shall run.

Comment: try Firestore Timestamp `toDate` method, like `firestore.Timestamp. toDate(eventDate.date)`

Comment: @IvanChernykh Vs code reacts to this line like this: Property 'toDate' does not exist on type 'typeof Timestamp'

Comment: so may be try `fromDate` for `tomorrow`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use moment and .diff().

```js
//Determine the unit of difference between
    const type = ["years","months","weeks","days","hours","minutes"]


    moment(tomorrow).diff(eventDate?.date.toDate(), type[3])
```

Comment: moment is not defined

Comment: npm install moment and.  import moment from 'moment';

Comment: Its actually with some changes, solved my problem completly, thank you sir